# How to add scoped styles depending on a global selector

Tags: css, vue.js

So Vue has `>>>` and `/deep/` for styling child components in scoped style:

```
<style scoped>
.local-class-name >>> .class-name-of-nested-component {
    ...
}
</style>
```

But I need is different.
How do I style a component using scoped style depending on a global class name?
Like this:

```
<style scoped>
.global-class-name .local-class-name {
    ...
}
</style>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that it only adds a **data** attribute to the last part of the selector.

So the example above already works, because it is compiled to the next code:

```
.global-class-name .local-class-name[data-v-ab5212] {
    ...
}
```